# Avoid returning it to the top of the page

Tags: php, html

I would like that when I press a submit button, the page remains at the position where it is currently, I know that it must be used:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'#ancre'.$i ?>" method="post">
```

and

```
<span id="#ancre"></span>
```

But I do not know where the positioned, at least when I try it does not work.
My code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'#ancre2'.$i ?>" method="post">
                  <h1>
                      <label for="reponse">Votre r&eacuteponse :</label>
                      <input class="question" type="text" name="reponse" 
                       placeholder="Avec l'unit&eacute" size="10" maxlength="10" 
                       />
                      <input type="submit" name="valider2" value="V&#233rifier 
                      r&#233ponse" />
                      <?php
                      if(isset($_POST['valider2'])) {
                          $reponse = -1;
                          $personne=$_POST['reponse'];
                          if ($personne == $reponse) {
                              echo 'Bravo vous avez juste !';
                          }
                          else {
                              echo 'Vous avez faux, concentrez-vous';
                          }
                      }
                      ?>
                      <span id="#ancre2"></span>
                  </h1>
</form>
```

Comment: it can be done by jquery and ajax.

Comment: Can not I just use html? Or php? The codes I have put are not enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `onSubmit="return false;"` to the `<form>` element. This will stop any form actions when submitted.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nb6uytL0/2/)

Comment: I confirm that it does not go up again, but after click strictly nothing happens, I have no answer coming from php.

Comment: You want to send it to a PHP page? Or do you want an `$.ajax`? I have created the code as a basis to not make it go up, you can customize what happens on the button click or `onSubmit` add a function.

Comment: You can use `$.ajax` to send a request to a PHP page that handles that data. I do not want to write your code for you, simply help you figure out how to approach it. Read about ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you for your help, given that I have just started, I would not too diversified too fast, I try to stay on html, but eventually that another day I would need it.

Answer (score 0):

Move `<span id="#ancre2"></span>` out of `h1` tag. And create a div with id 'ancre2' instead.

Seems to work after that.

Comment: Thank work! I have add <div id="ancre2"> before form and move <span id="#ancre2"></span> out of h1 tag

Comment: By the way, when I put several, it always brings me back to the end now, obviously I rename "anchor1" "anchor2" ... etc.